# Change the Cursor Image on Mac irrespective of which applicatoin is on Top

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

I want to  Change the Cursor Image on Mac irrespective of which application is on Top or in focus.

Can some one direct to related source code or some hints would be helpful?

I am using Carbon, C++

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, and I think that is a good thing.  The cursor image often provides information from the current application to the user, and background apps should not interfere with that communication.